# XSLT exclude Namespace without prefix

Tags: xslt

I have a XML with the following ns:

`<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">`

My XSLT only works when I manually remove the xmlns="urn:iso:std....
I have found the "exclude-result-prefixes" but I can't assign a prefix.
Is there a solution for this?

Thanks for the effort!

Comment: What do you mean by "*I can't assign a prefix*"? Of course you can: use any prefix you like. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node/34762628#34762628

Comment: Exclude-result-prefixes has absolutely nothing to do with this problem. Your problem is about namespaces in the source document, not in the result. (Search for "XSLT default namespace" and you will find a thousand other people who have asked the same question.)

Comment: We've been quite reluctant to close questions as duplicates in this community because it seems a bit unfriendly. However, for people coming here with a search, it's actually better if we try and reduce the number of unclosed instances of the same question.