# Split based on just tags

Tags: xslt, split

I am looking for a simple split of an xml file just based on tags; say 3 tags always repeat and need split as depicted below:

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test>
    <tag1>A</tag1>
    <tag2>B</tag2>
    <tag3>C</tag3>
    <tag1>1</tag1>
    <tag2>2</tag2>
    <tag3>3</tag3>
    <tag1>apple</tag1>
    <tag2>orange</tag2>
    <tag3>mango</tag3>
</Test>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<Root>
    <Test>
        <tag1>A</tag1>
        <tag2>B</tag2>
        <tag3>C</tag3>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <tag1>1</tag1>
        <tag2>2</tag2>
        <tag3>3</tag3>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <tag1>apple</tag1>
        <tag2>orange</tag2>
        <tag3>mango</tag3>
    </Test>
</Root>
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure is regular, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Test">
    <Root>
        <xsl:for-each select="tag1">
            <Test>
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::tag2[1] | following-sibling::tag3[1] "/>
            </Test>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Neat solution!!

Comment: very neat solution. it works great for simple tags; but if the tag has an xmlns associated, it doesn't.

Comment: Example - if the tag1 was like <tag1 xmlns = "abc">A</tag1>, it does not take it. How do I mention in xslt that xmlns should be included?

Comment: @Fkhader See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node/34762628#34762628

Comment: Perfect - that worked by using the concept of local-name(). Thank you! Now, a final question to take care of a possible scenario. What if the tag2 and tag3 are optional and can or cannot appear on the original xml? I tried to test by deleting tag2 of first occurance and it seems to copy the tag2 from 2nd occurance and paste in 1st split. Any simple solution to mention the tags are optional? Thank you so much for the above solutions @michael.hor257k

Comment: @Fkhader I did **not** suggest  "*using the concept of local-name()*"! I suggested - and still do - using a **prefix**. -- As for your new scenario, I suggest you post a new question, as it will require a radically different approach. Make sure to select XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 when posting.