# XML split based on optional tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, option-type

I am looking for a simple split of an xml file just based on tags; say 3 tags (optional) always repeat and need split as depicted below:

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test>
    <tag1>A</tag1>
    <tag2>B</tag2>
    <tag3>C</tag3>
    <tag1>1</tag1>
    <tag2>2</tag2>
    <tag3>3</tag3>
    <tag1>apple</tag1>
    <tag2>orange</tag2>
    <tag3>mango</tag3>
</Test>
```

Expected Output

```
<Root>
    <Test>
        <tag1>A</tag1>
        <tag2>B</tag2>
        <tag3>C</tag3>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <tag1>1</tag1>
        <tag2>2</tag2>
        <tag3>3</tag3>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <tag1>apple</tag1>
        <tag2>orange</tag2>
        <tag3>mango</tag3>
    </Test>
</Root>
```

The challenge here is that all 3 tags are optional and can or cannot appear in a block. If there weren't optional - my question was already answered here - [Split based on just tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049969/split-based-on-just-tags)

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Supposre you have tag1, tag2 and tag3 consecutively , how can you tell they belong to the same block, or it's just that, for instance, tag3 is missing in the first block and tag1 and tag2 are missing in the second? is it based on content?

Comment: fully agree with @Jayvee - you can put `<Test>`/`</Test>` around every single tag*n* and claim your question solved because there would be no way to prove that any belong together.

Comment: Re: "3 tags (optional) always repeat "  -- if they are optional, they cannot "always repeat" !

Comment: Indeed how do you define blocks? By just position under parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the requirement correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Test">
    <Root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag1">
    <Test>
        <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::*[1][self::tag2 or self::tag3]"/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::tag2]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[2][self::tag3] "/>
        </xsl:if>
    </Test>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag2[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::tag1])]">
    <Test>
        <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::*[1][self::tag3]"/>
    </Test>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag3[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::tag2 or self::tag1])]">
    <Test>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </Test>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will start a new group for each of these:

- a `tag1` element;
- a `tag2` element that does not immediately follow a `tag1` element;
- a `tag3` element that does not immediately follow a `tag2`  or a `tag1` element.

A group ends with `tag3`, or with the last element before the sequence breaks, whichever comes first.

Applied to the following test input:

**XML**

```
<Test>
    <tag2>B</tag2>
    <tag3>C</tag3>
    <tag1>1</tag1>
    <tag3>3</tag3>
    <tag1>apple</tag1>
    <tag2>orange</tag2>
    <tag1>A</tag1>
    <tag2>B</tag2>
    <tag1>1</tag1>
    <tag3>3</tag3>
    <tag3>mango</tag3>
    <tag1>A</tag1>
    <tag2>B</tag2>
    <tag3>C</tag3>
</Test>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
   <Test>
      <tag2>B</tag2>
      <tag3>C</tag3>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <tag1>1</tag1>
      <tag3>3</tag3>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <tag1>apple</tag1>
      <tag2>orange</tag2>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <tag1>A</tag1>
      <tag2>B</tag2>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <tag1>1</tag1>
      <tag3>3</tag3>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <tag3>mango</tag3>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <tag1>A</tag1>
      <tag2>B</tag2>
      <tag3>C</tag3>
   </Test>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thanks you! - that is exactly what was needed. If I had 5 tags instead of 5, just extend the same logic with all combinations - is that correct?

Comment: @Fkhader There may be a more elegant way if your group can be larger. I haven't really thought of it. Is it really possible for a "group" to have **any** of all possible combinations? Any constrain that applies may save a lot of code.

Comment: out of 5 tags, at least 3 will always be present - let's say 2, 3 and 5. Which means 1 and 4 are optional. Will that save a lot of code?

Comment: Yes, that means that a group starts with either 1 or 2, and ends with 5 -  and you could adapt the code above to that.

Comment: Or use my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution that can work with groups of any size, provided that at least one element of the group will always be present.

In this example there are up to 5 elements in each group, and element `tag3` will be present in each group:

**XML**

```
<Test>
    <tag1>A</tag1>
    <tag2>B</tag2>
    <tag3>C</tag3>
    <tag4>D</tag4>
    <tag5>E</tag5>
    <tag2>2</tag2>
    <tag3>3</tag3>
    <tag5>5</tag5>
    <tag3>C</tag3>
    <tag3>3</tag3>
    <tag4>4</tag4>
    <tag5>5</tag5>
    <tag2>B</tag2>
    <tag3>C</tag3>
    <tag4>D</tag4>
    <tag1>1</tag1>
    <tag3>3</tag3>
    <tag5>5</tag5>
</Test>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="elems-before" match="tag1 | tag2" use="generate-id(following-sibling::tag3[1])" />
<xsl:key name="elems-after"  match="tag4 | tag5" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::tag3[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/Test">
    <Root>
        <xsl:for-each select="tag3">
            <Test>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('elems-before', generate-id())"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('elems-after', generate-id())"/>
            </Test>
        </xsl:for-each>             
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
   <Test>
      <tag1>A</tag1>
      <tag2>B</tag2>
      <tag3>C</tag3>
      <tag4>D</tag4>
      <tag5>E</tag5>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <tag2>2</tag2>
      <tag3>3</tag3>
      <tag5>5</tag5>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <tag3>C</tag3>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <tag3>3</tag3>
      <tag4>4</tag4>
      <tag5>5</tag5>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <tag2>B</tag2>
      <tag3>C</tag3>
      <tag4>D</tag4>
   </Test>
   <Test>
      <tag1>1</tag1>
      <tag3>3</tag3>
      <tag5>5</tag5>
   </Test>
</Root>
```

Comment: Awesome! - Thank you @michael.hor257k