# XSLT Soap Message

Tags: xslt, soap

I can't change the name of tags in a SOAP response.
I saw a lot of postings about it, but I did not find an applicable solution.

My original XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <soap:Header>
      <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:4d6b87d8-fe14-4579-ac34-fe841c184a4b</MessageID>
      <RelatesTo RelationshipType="Reply" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:1f9b0c7e-f36c-4fa3-ac2b-2377b57b6634</RelatesTo>
      <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://xxx</Action>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <OP1 xmlns="http://xxx/">
         <OPR>
            <OPO>
               <Cod>..</Cod>
               <A1>hi my...</A1>

            </OPO>
         </OPR>
      </OP1>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to change A1 for ANAME.

My xsl is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="A1">
        <ANAME><xsl:apply-templates /></ANAME>
   </xsl:template>      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your XML, the `OP1` element and all its descendants are in the `xmlns="http://xxx/"` namespace. See here how to handle it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node/34762628#34762628 -- Note also that if you want `ANAME` to be in the same namespace, you must put it there. Otherwise you'll see `<ANAME xmlns="">hi my...</ANAME>` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a named namespace declaration for your namespace "http://xxx/" to your stylesheet element like this:

```
xmlns:aaa="http://xxx/"
```

Then your can match the `A1` elements with `aaa:A1` in your template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:aaa="http://xxx/">

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="aaa:A1">
     <xsl:element name="ANAME" namespace="http://xxx/">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
     </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>     

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Partial output:**

```
...
<soap:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <OP1 xmlns="http://xxx/">
        <OPR>
            <OPO>
                <Cod>..</Cod>
                <ANAME>hi my...</ANAME>

            </OPO>
        </OPR>
    </OP1>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: Thanks very much!!A final question, in the transformation, the new tag ANAME add atributtte xmlns="", how can i do to the transformation dont add it?

Comment: @AndresPastorini: I just retested my XSLT with your input XML and the result is as given in my answer. Constructing my answer, I put some special consideration on removing these empty `xslns=""` attributes in the output. This is achieved by setting the `namespace="..."` attribute of `ANAME` to the same value as the surrounding namespace (in this case `<OP1 xmlns="http://xxx/">`). This has been realized in my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!!

Comment: @AndresPastorini: Thank you for your appreciation. I'm glad to read that. But if my answer has been helpful, an approved SO way of showing that is accepting my answer.