# filter child value and copy parent in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

im trying to filter some book records from a larger metadata file. I only need records with a specific term in the field "rights". If the field contains "インターネット公開" it should go to the result every other record is unessary.

Sample xml:

```
<ListRecords>
  <record>
    <header>
    </header>
    <metadata>
      <title>農林時報</title>
      <creator>農林省</creator>
      <rights>国立国会図書館</rights>
    </metadata>
  </record>
  <record>
    <header>
    </header>
    <metadata>
      <title>大和本草</title>
      <creator>貝原篤信</creator>
      <rights>インターネット公開（保護期間満了）</rights>
    </metadata>
  </record>
</ListRecords>
```

My xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> 

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-16" indent="no" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:if test="contains(current(), 'インターネット公開')">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Result should show the hole xml structure but only records with the specified term.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: If your result should retain the existing structure, why do you have `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"`?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt will copy only elements that contain the prescribed string in their own text value. If you want to copy entire records, why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ListRecords">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="record[contains(metadata/rights, 'インターネット公開')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, im testing your xslt with oxygen. In the result there are only values but no tags and it copys every record.

Comment: Maybe you can help me one more time because i think i cant get along with xslt. I uploaded the original xml: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5Fe/3 I tryed my sample in Oxygen but i dont know why its not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HanzoD. It's not working, because your input (a) has a different structure (`ListRecords` is not the root element) and (b) it has a default namespace that needs to be taken into account.

Comment: Ive tryed several other configurations of course. Added the namespaces and other structure but didnt work, see: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5Fe/5

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node/34762628#34762628 -- P.S. I believe this question is answered. If you have other issues that you're unable to solve on your own, please post a new question.