# Get rid of XML namespaces from HTML generated by XSL in PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt

I am using a following PHP routine to transform XML using XSL into HTML. The problem is that during the transformation xmlns namespaces are getting inserted as attributes into the h2 element.

PHP:

```
$url = "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";

$xml_doc = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_doc);

$xsl_doc = new DOMDocument();
$xsl_doc->load("currency_transform.xsl");

$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsl->ImportStyleSheet($xsl_doc);
echo $xsl->transformToXML($xml);
```

XML (from link above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time='2017-04-03'>
            <Cube currency='USD' rate='1.0661'/>
            <Cube currency='JPY' rate='118.64'/>
            <Cube currency='BGN' rate='1.9558'/>
            <Cube currency='CZK' rate='27.044'/>
            <Cube currency='DKK' rate='7.4374'/>
            <Cube currency='GBP' rate='0.85260'/>
            <Cube currency='HUF' rate='308.68'/>
            <Cube currency='PLN' rate='4.2279'/>
            <Cube currency='RON' rate='4.5495'/>
            <Cube currency='SEK' rate='9.5145'/>
            <Cube currency='CHF' rate='1.0682'/>
            <Cube currency='NOK' rate='9.1468'/>
            <Cube currency='HRK' rate='7.4305'/>
            <Cube currency='RUB' rate='60.0802'/>
            <Cube currency='TRY' rate='3.8831'/>
            <Cube currency='AUD' rate='1.4012'/>
            <Cube currency='BRL' rate='3.3314'/>
            <Cube currency='CAD' rate='1.4229'/>
            <Cube currency='CNY' rate='7.3423'/>
            <Cube currency='HKD' rate='8.2858'/>
            <Cube currency='IDR' rate='14203.12'/>
            <Cube currency='ILS' rate='3.8690'/>
            <Cube currency='INR' rate='69.2805'/>
            <Cube currency='KRW' rate='1191.09'/>
            <Cube currency='MXN' rate='19.9794'/>
            <Cube currency='MYR' rate='4.7202'/>
            <Cube currency='NZD' rate='1.5226'/>
            <Cube currency='PHP' rate='53.456'/>
            <Cube currency='SGD' rate='1.4899'/>
            <Cube currency='THB' rate='36.658'/>
            <Cube currency='ZAR' rate='14.4506'/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01"
  xmlns:eurofxref="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <xsl:output method = "html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<body>
  <h2>Kursy walut</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Waluta</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Kurs</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="gesmes:Envelope/eurofxref:Cube/eurofxref:Cube/eurofxref:Cube">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@currency"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@rate"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Resulting HTML code:

```
<div class="currency_table">
<h2 xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns:eurofxref="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">Kursy walut</h2><table xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns:eurofxref="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref" border="1">
<tbody><tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th style="text-align:left">Waluta</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Kurs</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>USD</td>
<td>1.0661</td>
</tr>

...

<td>ZAR</td>
<td>14.4506</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

My question is: how do I get rid of xmlns attributes from the h2 element? Why is it even there?

Comment: Works for me. I get <html xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns:eurofxref="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref"><body>
<h2>Kursy walut</h2>
<table border="1">
...

Comment: Yes, but I do not really want them. Check out [validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fkucharskipawel.cba.pl%2Findex.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)

Comment: Please post an example of the input, so that we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the namespaces from your XSL stylesheet and ignore namespaces in your for-each select to avoid namespaces in your output, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method = "html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
      <h2>Kursy walut</h2>
      <table border="1" >
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <th style="text-align:left">Waluta</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Kurs</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='Cube']/*[local-name()='Cube'][@currency]">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@currency"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@rate"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output then looks like:

```
<html><body>
<h2>Kursy walut</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th style="text-align:left">Waluta</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Kurs</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>USD</td>
<td>1.0661</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>JPY</td>
<td>118.64</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>BGN</td>
<td>1.9558</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CZK</td>
<td>27.044</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>DKK</td>
<td>7.4374</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks! :D that helped a lot, especially the XPath.

Comment: Added an extra [@currency] to avoid a blank row you might get.

Answer (score 3):

> how do I get rid of xmlns attributes from the h2 element?

Try changing this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01"
  xmlns:eurofxref="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
```

to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01"
  xmlns:eurofxref="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref"
  exclude-result-prefixes="gesmes eurofxref">
```

Untested, because no input example was provided. BTW, a namespace declaration is not an attribute.

---

> Why is it even there?

Because apparently your input nodes are in a namespace and you need those prefixes to address them - see: [XSLT Transform doesn't work until I remove root node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node/34762628?s=1|0.1074#34762628)

Comment: @KrisOye No, it wasn't. The input to an XSL transformation is an XML document.

Comment: Well, the URL to the source was included which was good enough for me.  I submitted an edit but I'm guessing someone has already done the same.