# Flat xml to hierarchial xml with new tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this xml that i need styled, but ican't even get a for.each to work properly: I try to, for each CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE, if the NAME is 'HEADER' then ...

I want help to get started... so that i at least can get the statements correct, i have read and read...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()"> 
    <xsl:element name="SEPA_HEADER">  
        <xsl:value-of select=". = HEADER"/>
        <xsl:if test="*//NAME[text() = 'HEADER']">
          <p>x</p>          
        </xsl:if>               
        <xsl:for-each select="CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE/MESSAGE_LINE/CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE">
          <P>1</P>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="//NAME[text() = 'HEADER']">
            <P>CHOOSE</P>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <p>123</p>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>   
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use VS2013

my nasty xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:ifsworld-com:connectivity_message" ID="CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE-6.0">
  <APPLICATION_MESSAGE_ID>N/A</APPLICATION_MESSAGE_ID>
  <APPLICATION_RECEIVER_ID>N/A</APPLICATION_RECEIVER_ID>
  <CLASS_ID>ISO20022</CLASS_ID>
  <CONNECTIVITY_VERSION>2.1.0</CONNECTIVITY_VERSION>
  <EXEC_TIME>2017-04-06T15:20:49</EXEC_TIME>
  <MEDIA_CODE>EDI</MEDIA_CODE>
  <OBJSTATE>Released</OBJSTATE>
  <RECEIVER>BANK</RECEIVER>
  <SENDER>IFS</SENDER>
  <STATE>Released</STATE>
  <VERSION>N/A</VERSION>
  <MESSAGE_LINES>
    <CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
      <C01>ORDER_ID</C01>
      <C02>MESSAGE_ID</C02>
      <C03>CONTROL_SUM</C03>
      <C04>PURCHASENO</C04>
      <MESSAGE_LINE>1.0</MESSAGE_LINE>
      <NAME>HEADER</NAME>
      <STATE>Posted</STATE>
    </CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
    <CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
      <C01>P1</C01>
      <C02>line_rec_.Line_No</C02>
      <MESSAGE_LINE>2.0</MESSAGE_LINE>
      <NAME>PAYMENT</NAME>
      <STATE>Posted</STATE>
    </CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
    <CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
      <C01>P1</C01>
      <C02>T1.1</C02>
      <MESSAGE_LINE>3.0</MESSAGE_LINE>
      <NAME>TRANS</NAME>
      <STATE>Posted</STATE>
    </CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
    <CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
      <C01>P1</C01>
      <C02>T1.2</C02>
      <MESSAGE_LINE>4.0</MESSAGE_LINE>
      <NAME>TRANS</NAME>
      <STATE>Posted</STATE>
    </CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
    <CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
      <C01>P1</C01>
      <C02>T1.3</C02>
      <MESSAGE_LINE>5.0</MESSAGE_LINE>
      <NAME>TRANS</NAME>
      <STATE>Posted</STATE>
    </CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
    <CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
      <C01>P2</C01>
      <C02>line_rec_.Line_No</C02>
      <MESSAGE_LINE>6.0</MESSAGE_LINE>
      <NAME>PAYMENT</NAME>
      <STATE>Posted</STATE>
    </CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
    <CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
      <C01>P2</C01>
      <C02>T2.1</C02>
      <MESSAGE_LINE>7.0</MESSAGE_LINE>
      <NAME>TRANS</NAME>
      <STATE>Posted</STATE>
    </CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
    <CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
      <C01>P2</C01>
      <C02>T2.2</C02>
      <MESSAGE_LINE>8.0</MESSAGE_LINE>
      <NAME>TRANS</NAME>
      <STATE>Posted</STATE>
    </CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
    <CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
      <C01>P3</C01>
      <C02>line_rec_.Line_No</C02>
      <MESSAGE_LINE>9.0</MESSAGE_LINE>
      <NAME>PAYMENT</NAME>
      <STATE>Posted</STATE>
    </CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
    <CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
      <C01>P3</C01>
      <C02>T3.1</C02>
      <MESSAGE_LINE>10.0</MESSAGE_LINE>
      <NAME>TRANS</NAME>
      <STATE>Posted</STATE>
    </CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
    <CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
      <C01>P3</C01>
      <C02>T3.2</C02>
      <MESSAGE_LINE>11.0</MESSAGE_LINE>
      <NAME>TRANS</NAME>
      <STATE>Posted</STATE>
    </CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
    <CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
      <C01>P3</C01>
      <C02>T3.3</C02>
      <MESSAGE_LINE>12.0</MESSAGE_LINE>
      <NAME>TRANS</NAME>
      <STATE>Posted</STATE>
    </CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE>
  </MESSAGE_LINES>
</CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE>
```

Comment: I found the value of the chils node with           <xsl:value-of select="//CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE[NAME/text() = 'HEADER']/C01/text()"/> now i notiched that all the output xml are in one line... Any ideas?

Comment: It would seem the _xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:ifsworld-com:connectivity_message" ID="CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE-6.0"_ in your CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE node is causing issues with the processing are those attributes necessary in your source xml?

Comment: I have deleted the linie and know at least i can use some xpath syntax.

Comment: @Lise There is no need to modify your XML; XSLT can handle any XML input. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node/34762628#34762628  There are other issues with your attempt, but this will give you a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear from your post what you want for the output XML.  For a more XSL-y way of processing the input XML, I would suggest the following.  Using templates avoids any need for `for-each` in the way you appear to be trying to use it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0"

    xmlns="urn:ifsworld-com:connectivity_message"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:ifsworld-com:connectivity_message">
    <!-- Note the `xpath-default-namespace` line here: this is only allowed in XSLT 2.0 and newer.
        The input XLIFF file itself specifies this URI as the unprefixed namespace for the whole file.
        If we don't specify this as the XPath default namespace, we have to specify element names
        in ugly workaround syntax, such as `*[local-name() = 'MESSAGE_LINES']`. -->

    <!-- Indent for easier human readability. -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Strip space so that skipped elements don't result in blank whitespace in the output. -->
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Start at the top -->
    <xsl:template match="/CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE">
        <!-- Here, we just copy the element.  Change if you need something different in your output. -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- I assume here that you want to also copy over all of the elemnt attributes. -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <!-- Now, just pass in all the children elements for further processing. -->
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MESSAGE_LINES">
        <!-- From your sample code, I have no clear idea if this is what 
            you intend for the SEPA_HEADER element.  Change as appropriate. -->
        <SEPA_HEADER>
            <!-- Now pass in all children of the MESSAGE_LINES element
                (in this case, all the CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE structures).-->
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </SEPA_HEADER>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- Your sample code had:
                    <xsl:when test="//NAME[text() = 'HEADER']">
                The // here means that this is TRUE if there is *any* 
                NAME *anywhere in the file* that has text of 'HEADER'.
                Given your sample file, this will *always* be true, no
                matter where we are.  I suspect you instead need to 
                check if _this specific CONNECTIVITY_MESSAGE_LINE_ has
                a NAME element with text of 'HEADER'. -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- You can test the text value of an element by simply evaluating `.` ("this").
                    You can, but you don't need to, evaluate using `text()`. -->
                <xsl:when test="NAME[. = 'HEADER']">
                    <p>CHOOSE</p>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <p>123</p>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <!-- I assume here that you want to copy all the children.
                Change as appropriate for your needs. -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Suppress output of anything else for which we do not have a specific template defined. -->
    <xsl:template match="*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should get you started.  Have a look, read the comments, and let us know what questions you might still have.