# Difficulty in Accessing Attribute value (Xpath) XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, ibm-datapower

I could not able to access PartNumber/Description value  under attribute tag with below xpath but and soap xml is given below.Let me know any further details required.

Please help on this.Thanks inadvance!.

Xpath being used And SOAP XML Message:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResponse']/*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResult']/*[local-name()='CustomerPart']/@*[local-name()='PartNumber']"/> 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header />
   <s:Body>
      <PullCustomerPartsPricingResponse xmlns="http://cdx.dealerbuilt.com/Api/0.99/">
         <PullCustomerPartsPricingResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DealerBuilt.BaseApi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:CustomerPart>
               <a:Placement>
                  <a:GroupId>10</a:GroupId>
               </a:Placement>
               <a:Attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DealerBuilt.Models.Parts">
                  <b:AddedDate>2017-12-19T00:00:00</b:AddedDate>
                  <b:DealerPartId>287925</b:DealerPartId>
                  <b:Description>BAT (51/500AMP85)</b:Description>
                  <b:PartNumber>31500SB2yy1M</b:PartNumber>
                  <b:QuantityLostMonthToDate>0</b:QuantityLostMonthToDate>
               </a:Attributes>
               <a:PartKey>GZ287925</a:PartKey>
               <a:CustomerListPrice xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DealerBuilt.Models">
                  <b:Amount>130.49</b:Amount>
                  <b:Currency>UsDollar</b:Currency>
               </a:CustomerListPrice>
            </a:CustomerPart>
         </PullCustomerPartsPricingResult>
      </PullCustomerPartsPricingResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Regards
Vardhan

Comment: Namespaces are to be used, not avoided. See; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node/34762628#34762628

Answer (score 0):

You have ended your long xpath expression with this..

```
/@*[local-name()='PartNumber']
```

But `PartNumber` is not an attribute. It is an element named `PartNumber` that is a child of an element that happened to be named `Attributes`, but that does not actually make it an attribute in XML terms!

It should look like this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']
                        /*[local-name()='Body']
                        /*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResponse']
                        /*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResult']
                        /*[local-name()='CustomerPart']
                        /*[local-name()='Attributes']
                        /*[local-name()='PartNumber']"/>
```

Although it would be really better if you declared the namespaces in your XSLT and used then in your xpath.

Answer (score 0):

NameSpaces from the request XML need to be used in xslt as well.Following xsl gave the PartNumber value.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DealerBuilt.BaseApi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DealerBuilt.Models.Parts">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResponse']/*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResult']/*[local-name()='CustomerPart']/*[local-name()='Attributes']/*[local-name()='PartNumber']"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```