# Count for ALL instances of a field (even in other segments)

Tags: xslt

The TOTAL field needs to count ALL ITEM fields for ALL segments. Not just the ITEM fields inside the same segment

I've already tried changing the context by adding another ./ in the beginning of the xpath.

```
<xsl:template match="nm:EPCISDocument">
  <MESSAGE>
      <PALLET>
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='ObjectEvent'][substring(epcList/epc,1,16) = 'urn:epc:id:sgtin']">
          <MATERIAL>
            <BOX>
              <TOTAL>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(./epcList/epc[substring(.,1,16) = 'urn:epc:id:sgtin'])"/>
              </TOTAL>
              <xsl:for-each select="./epcList/epc[substring(.,1,16) = 'urn:epc:id:sgtin']">
                <SERIES>
                  <ITEM>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(.,'.'),'.')"/>
                  </ITEM>
                </SERIES>
            </BOX>
          </MATERIAL>
      </PALLET>
  </MESSAGE>
```

This is a sample input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<n0:EPCISDocument xmlns:n0="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" schemaVersion="1.1">
  <ObjectEvent>
    <epcList>
      <epc>urn:epc:id:sgtin:999999999.0000.0000000001</epc>
      <epc>urn:epc:id:sgtin:999999999.0000.0000000002</epc>
    </epcList>
  </ObjectEvent>
  <ObjectEvent>
    <epcList>
      <epc>urn:epc:id:sgtin:999999999.0000.0000000003</epc>
      <epc>urn:epc:id:sgtin:999999999.0000.0000000004</epc>
      <epc>urn:epc:id:sgtin:999999999.0000.0000000005</epc>
    </epcList>
  </ObjectEvent>
</n0:EPCISDocument>
```

The expected should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MESSAGE>
  <PALLET>
    <MATERIAL>
      <BOX>
        <TOTAL>5</TOTAL>
        <SERIES>
          <ITEM>0000000001</ITEM>
        </SERIES>
        <SERIES>
          <ITEM>0000000002</ITEM>
        </SERIES>
      </BOX>
    </MATERIAL>
    <MATERIAL>
      <BOX>
        <TOTAL>5</TOTAL>
        <SERIES>
          <ITEM>0000000003</ITEM>
        </SERIES>
        <SERIES>
          <ITEM>0000000004</ITEM>
        </SERIES>
                <SERIES>
          <ITEM>0000000005</ITEM>
        </SERIES>
      </BOX>
    </MATERIAL>
  </PALLET>
</MESSAGE>
```

But right now based on the code, I'm getting this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MESSAGE>
  <PALLET>
    <MATERIAL>
      <BOX>
        <TOTAL>2</TOTAL>
        <SERIES>
          <ITEM>0000000001</ITEM>
        </SERIES>
        <SERIES>
          <ITEM>0000000002</ITEM>
        </SERIES>
      </BOX>
    </MATERIAL>
    <MATERIAL>
      <BOX>
        <TOTAL>3</TOTAL>
        <SERIES>
          <ITEM>0000000003</ITEM>
        </SERIES>
        <SERIES>
          <ITEM>0000000004</ITEM>
        </SERIES>
                <SERIES>
          <ITEM>0000000005</ITEM>
        </SERIES>
      </BOX>
    </MATERIAL>
  </PALLET>
</MESSAGE>
```

Comment: `//*[local-name()='ObjectEvent']` You should never have to use such hack. If the source element  is in a namespace, use a prefix - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node/34762628#34762628

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <MESSAGE>
        <PALLET>
            <xsl:variable name="total" select="count(ObjectEvent/epcList/epc)" />
            <xsl:for-each select="ObjectEvent">
                <MATERIAL>
                    <BOX>
                        <TOTAL>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$total"/>
                        </TOTAL>
                        <xsl:for-each select="epcList/epc">
                            <SERIES>
                                <ITEM>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(., '.'), '.')"/>
                                </ITEM>
                            </SERIES>
                        </xsl:for-each> 
                    </BOX>
                </MATERIAL>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </PALLET>
    </MESSAGE>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry Sir michael, I'm getting a 0 for the TOTAL

Comment: It works as expected for me - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZX9

Comment: okay sir let me fiddle around with my code. it's weird that mine says 0 zero.

Comment: Perhaps `ObjectEvent` is also in a namespace? Are there any occurrences of a default namespace declaration of `xmlns="...."`  in your actual XML?

Comment: ah you are right Sir Tim! I missed something in my source payload and xslt sorry. I cannot use template match /*

Comment: @XSLTnewbie If your input XML is different from the one you posted, then please edit your question and show what your actual input looks like.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, i have edited the xslt. i have added <xsl:template match="nm:EPCISDocument"> at the start. that's the only difference

Comment: tried this also:           <xsl:variable name="total">
              <xsl:value-of select="count(//*[local-name()='ObjectEvent'][substring(epcList/epc,1,16) = 'urn:epc:id:sgtin'])"/>
          </xsl:variable> , count is showing an incorrect sum

Comment: @XSLTnewbie We are not making progress here. You say that **my** XSLT does not work with your XML, so **your** XSLT is irrelevant. If your **XML** is similar to what you posted, then my XSLT will produce the expected result.

Comment: Thanks sir @michael.hor257k. I forgot the 2 parent segments above ObjectEvent. It's working now.