# M trying to swap shipfromlocationref to shiptolocationref for the below XML

Tags: xml, xslt, tags, swap

I'm trying to swap two of the values in my XML below,
In my below xml **ShipFromLocationRef** has value RO91 and **ShipToLocationRef** has value 6449706. My requirement is to swap R091 to **ShipToLocationRef** and 6449706 to **ShipFromLocationRef**.

Requesting you to please help here
Below is my XML what i want to get transformed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Transmission xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<TransmissionHeader>
</TransmissionHeader>
<TransmissionBody>
<GLogXMLElement>
<Release>
<ReleaseGid>
<Gid>
<DomainName>M02</DomainName>
<Xid>4008060679_XD</Xid>
</Gid>
</ReleaseGid>
<TransactionCode>IU</TransactionCode>
<ShipFromLocationRef>
<LocationRef>
<LocationGid>
<Gid>
<DomainName>M02</DomainName>
<Xid>RO91</Xid>
</Gid>
</LocationGid>
</LocationRef>
</ShipFromLocationRef>
<ShipToLocationRef>
<LocationRef>
<LocationGid>
<Gid>
<DomainName>M02</DomainName>
<Xid>6449706</Xid>
</Gid>
</LocationGid>
</LocationRef>
</ShipToLocationRef>
</Release>
</GLogXMLElement>
</TransmissionBody>
</Transmission>
```

Belo is my XSL code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:Transmission="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
                <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                                <xsl:copy>
                                                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                                </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Transmission:ShipFromLocationRef/LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|../Transmission:ShipToLocationRef/LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid/text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Transmission:ShipToLocationRef/LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|../Transmission:ShipFromLocationRef/LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid/text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My expected output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Transmission xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <TransmissionHeader>
    </TransmissionHeader>
    <TransmissionBody>
    <GLogXMLElement>
    <Release>
    <ReleaseGid>
    <Gid>
    <DomainName>M02</DomainName>
    <Xid>4008060679_XD</Xid>
    </Gid>
    </ReleaseGid>
    <TransactionCode>IU</TransactionCode>
    <ShipFromLocationRef>
    <LocationRef>
    <LocationGid>
    <Gid>
    <DomainName>M02</DomainName>
    <Xid>**6449706**</Xid>
    </Gid>
    </LocationGid>
    </LocationRef>
    </ShipFromLocationRef>
    <ShipToLocationRef>
    <LocationRef>
    <LocationGid>
    <Gid>
    <DomainName>M02</DomainName>
    <Xid>**RO91**</Xid>
    </Gid>
    </LocationGid>
    </LocationRef>
    </ShipToLocationRef>
    </Release>
    </GLogXMLElement>
    </TransmissionBody>
    </Transmission>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add your XML.... Also, don't forget to show your expected output too. Thanks!

Comment: i have added now, request you to please help

Comment: Are you sure your XML is in the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` namespace?

Comment: yes, same same ns m using in both XSL and XML

Comment: Is that your decision? I don't think it's the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, this returns the expected result:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:ShipFromLocationRef//ns0:Xid">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="//ns0:ShipToLocationRef//ns0:Xid"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:ShipToLocationRef//ns0:Xid">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="//ns0:ShipFromLocationRef//ns0:Xid"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked out.. can u please let me know why u introduced ns here? n how it worked out

Comment: Why not? You can use any prefix you like, it makes no difference at all. But you **must** use a prefix - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node/34762628#34762628