# xslt for ubl xml don't get any value

Tags: xml, xslt, ubl

I have a .xslt file but it doesn't give any result.
I think i'm missing some namespace or something but i don't see the problem.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
<xsl:template match="/">
<DataSet>
    <ifch.t_factuurnr><xsl:value-of select="Invoice/cbc:ID"/></ifch.t_factuurnr>
</DataSet>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    <cbc:ID>200858</cbc:ID>
</Invoice>
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm missing?

Comment: `Invoice` is in a namespace too and needs a prefix - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node/34762628?r=SearchResults&s=1|23.7140#34762628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a :... :wix to my namespaces, but is it possible to just don't declare the namespace and take everything inside the first node?

```
<xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
<xsl:template match="/">
```

changed to:

```
<xmlns:wix="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
<xsl:template match="/">
<ifch.t_factuurnr><xsl:value-of select="wix:Invoice/cbc:ID"/></ifch.t_factuurnr>
```

Comment: Unless you use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor where you could use `<xsl:stylesheet xpath-default-namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" ..>` there is no compact and efficient way with XSLT 1 or with an XSLT 1 processor to avoid declaring and using the prefix.