# xslt to copy elements and value only when condition is true

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my xml:

```
<Orderdetails>
<OrderPlace>CDGV</OrderPlace>
<OrderID>1234</OrderID>
<OrderStatus>Active<OrderStatus>
</Orderdetails>
```

Below is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:choose> 
 <xsl:when test = "OrderStatus=Active"> 
    <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>             
    <xsl:otherwise> 
    Order Status Inactive
     </xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose> 
    <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to copy all the elements and values only when the  value is 'Active' in the input xml, Otherwise it should display "Order status as Inactive".Can you please let me know where should I make changes in my XSLT ?

Comment: First thing is in your test="" you are refering to Order_Status, but the name of the node is OrderStatus.

Comment: Also add your expected output to your question, your XSLT seems rather complicated for something simple.

Comment: I have rolled your question back to what it was when I answered it. If necessary, ask a new question with your new problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to copy all the elements and values only when the value is 'Active' in the input xml, Otherwise it should display "Order status as Inactive"

This would be easy to achieve using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="Orderdetails">
    <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test="OrderStatus='Active'"> 
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
        </xsl:when>          
        <xsl:otherwise>Order Status Inactive</xsl:otherwise> 
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However this has a flaw: when the test is true, the result will be a copy of the source XML document; when it is false, the result will be a string.

Note also that this assumes that there will be only one `Orderdetails` element.

Comment: This is my actual request. Where should make changes in XSLT to make it work?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762628/3016153 If not, ask a new question with your new problem.

Comment: I'm not able to post similar ques. Can you please help how to represent in xslt if input tag is represented with namespaces -mbl:orderdetails, mbl:orderstatus ?

Comment: I explained this in the link above.

Comment: I have modified as <xsl:when test = "MBL:OrderStatus=Active"> and in <xsl:template match="MBL:Orderdetails"> but still not working.