# XSLT 1.0 Grouping xml nodes by value of a child

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, xslt-1.0, biztalk

I am using XSLT 1.0

I have an input message i am trying to transform.
This input messages has the following redondant structure, composed of 4 types of nodes A, B, Order, Article, **which are always in the same order**:

```
A
B
Order0
Article100
A
B
Order1
Article101
A
B
Order0
Article102
...
```

I would like to group the nodes to produce the following output:

```
A
B
Order0
Article100
Article102
A
B
Order1
Article101
A
B
```

In the output, i don't want any duplicates of the `Order` node; The nodes `A` and `B` should not be moved.

Here are complete XML messages.
The key for the grouping is the field `Key` inside of the `Order` node

**Input**:

```
<Messages>
    <Message>
        <A>
            <Number>100</Number>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </A>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <B>
            <Number>100</Number>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </B>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Order>
            <Key>100</Key>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Order>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Article>
            <Key>78</Key>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Article>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <A>
            <Number>600</Number>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </A>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <B>
            <Number>601</Number>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </B>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Order>
            <Key>101</Key>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Order>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Article>
            <Key>55</Key>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Article>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <A>
            <Number>799</Number>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </A>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <B>
            <Number>798</Number>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </B>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Order>
            <Key>100</Key>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Order>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Article>
            <Key>32</Key>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Article>
    </Message>
</Messages>
```

**Output**:

```
<Messages>
    <Message>
        <A>
            <Number>100</Number>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </A>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <B>
            <Number>100</Number>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </B>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Order>
            <Key>100</Key>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Order>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Article>
            <Key>78</Key>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Article>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Article>
            <Key>32</Key>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Article>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <A>
            <Number>600</Number>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </A>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <B>
            <Number>601</Number>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </B>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Order>
            <Key>101</Key>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Order>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <Article>
            <Key>55</Key>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </Article>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <A>
            <Number>799</Number>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </A>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <B>
            <Number>798</Number>
            <SomeData>somedata</SomeData>
            <SomeData2>somedata</SomeData2>
        </B>
    </Message>
</Messages>
```

I was thinking about using the Muenchian grouping but without success.
I am not quite sure it is what I am looking for.

This is for a Biztalk mapping, so I could also work with Biztalk mapping and functoids.

Comment: Doesn't Biztalk 2020 also allow XSLT 3?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have the last version of Biztalk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it (I think):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="order" match="Message[Order]" use="Order/Key" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Message[Order]">
    <xsl:if test="count(. | key('order', Order/Key)[1]) = 1">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('order', Order/Key)/following-sibling::Message[1]"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Message[Article]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I just found out that this stylesheet doesn't work anymore when I add a namespace to the input document, even when i specify the namespace in the xsl.
I found somebody with the exact same issue: https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200711/msg00376.html

Comment: Of course it doesn't - see here why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762628/3016153.