# XSLT: Find the way to transform to XML

Tags: xslt

I have XML in the following format:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<MES_VEHICLE_STATUS_DESCRIPTOR xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="MOM.Production"  PRODUCTIONORDER="000001995795" >
  <POSECTION LOCATION="" />
  <ORDERSECTION SALESORDER=""  />
  <MATERIALCONSUMPTIONSECTION>
    <MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION DESC="car" QTY="1.000" WORKPLACE="3001_GAT101LH">BIN1000004</MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION>
    <MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION DESC="PLAIN_WASHER" QTY="1.000" WORKPLACE="3001_GAT101LH">WRE20000018</MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION>
    <MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION DESC="car" QTY="1.000" WORKPLACE="3001_GAT101LH">BIN1000003</MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION>
    
  </MATERIALCONSUMPTIONSECTION>
</MES_VEHICLE_STATUS_DESCRIPTOR>
```

and output should look like that:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:mat="http://mes.com/ScrapManagement">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mat:DT_SCRAPMANAGEMENT_MES_REQ>
         <DATA>
            <PlantCode>3002</PlantCode>
            <SAPOrder>000001995795</SAPOrder>
            <Quantity>1.000</Quantity>
            <PartNo>BIN1000004</PartNo>
            <WorkPlace>3001_GAT101LH</WorkPlace>
         </DATA>
         <DATA>
            <PlantCode>3002</PlantCode>
            <SAPOrder>000001995795</SAPOrder>
            <Quantity>1.000</Quantity>
            <PartNo>WRE20000018</PartNo>
            <WorkPlace>3001_GAT101LH</WorkPlace>
         </DATA>
         <DATA>
            <PlantCode>3002</PlantCode>
            <SAPOrder>000001995795</SAPOrder>
            <Quantity>1.000</Quantity>
            <PartNo>BIN1000003</PartNo>
            <WorkPlace>3001_GAT101LH</WorkPlace>
         </DATA>
                     
      </mat:DT_SCRAPMANAGEMENT_MES_REQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My XSLT to transform

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    >
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
    <xsl:template match="MES_VEHICLE_STATUS_DESCRIPTOR">
        <soapenv:Envelope
            xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:mat="http://mes.com/ScrapManagement">
            <soapenv:Header />
            <soapenv:Body>
                <xsl:element name="mat:DT_SCRAPMANAGEMENT_MES_REQ">
                    <xsl:variable name="po" select="@PRODUCTIONORDER" />
                    <xsl:for-each select="MATERIALCONSUMPTIONSECTION/MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION">
                        <DATA>
                            <PlantCode>
                                <xsl:text>3002</xsl:text>
                            </PlantCode>
                            <SAPOrder>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$po" />
                            </SAPOrder>
                            <Quantity>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@QTY" />
                            </Quantity>
                            <PartNo>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </PartNo>
                            <WorkPlace>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@WORKPLACE" />
                            </WorkPlace>
                        </DATA>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If i delete xmlns="MOM.Production" in XML file, the transformation is OK. But if have it in xml file, cannot transform. I use website: `https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php` and show the error: `Error:DOMDocument::loadXML(): xmlns: URI MOM.Production is not absolute in Entity, line: 2`.
I don't understand what is reason.
I don't understand what is reason

Comment: Please do not add problems to the question after it has been answered. The solution to your new issue can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762628/3016153.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you had in mind is probably more or less this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

  <xsl:template match="MES_VEHICLE_STATUS_DESCRIPTOR">
    <xsl:for-each select="MATERIALCONSUMPTIONSECTION/MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION">
      <xsl:element name="DATA">
        <xsl:element name="PRODUCTIONORDER">
          <xsl:value-of select="../../@PRODUCTIONORDER" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="QTY">
          <xsl:value-of select="@QTY" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="MATERIAL">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think you have to understand the difference between relative and absolute paths in the XPATH expressions your are using to select the correct nodes.

When you are inside a template matching the node `MES_VEHICLE_STATUS_DESCRIPTOR`, you don't use absolute paths like `/MATERIALCONSUMPTIONSECTION/MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION` (which doesn't exist in this case), but paths relative to this node, as `MATERIALCONSUMPTIONSECTION/MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION`.

When you are inside a `<xsl:for-each select="MATERIALCONSUMPTIONSECTION/MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION">` loop, you have to select the nodes with relative paths like `text()`, `../../@PRODUCTIONORDER` or `@QTY`. Notice the `@` telling the QTY and PRODUCTIONORDER are attribute type nodes.

Finally, your current output is no well formed XML since it lacks a root element.

Personnaly, I would replace the `<xsl:element>` tag by its litteral value and avoid the computation of a constant field accross a loop:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

  <xsl:template match="MES_VEHICLE_STATUS_DESCRIPTOR">
    <xsl:variable name="po" select="@PRODUCTIONORDER" />
    <xsl:for-each select="MATERIALCONSUMPTIONSECTION/MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION">
      <DATA>
        <PRODUCTIONORDER><xsl:value-of select="$po" /></PRODUCTIONORDER>
        <QTY><xsl:value-of select="@QTY" /></QTY>
        <MATERIAL><xsl:value-of select="." /></MATERIAL>
      </DATA>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Use literal result elements instead of `xsl:element`. Also consider using a variable for PRODUCTIONORDER instead of repeatedly looking it up from the ancestor node.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I totally agree with you. In this case, I wanted to do the minimal changes to make the code of the PO work. I will edit my solution above.

Comment: One more: use `<xsl:variable name="po" select="@PRODUCTIONORDER"/>` instead of creating a text node inside the variable.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I agree again.

Comment: @michael.hor257k And why not also `<MATERIAL><xsl:value-of select="." /></MATERIAL>` instead of selecting `text()`...

Comment: @PierreFrançois, thanks for your support. But i dont know why if i add 2 tag same level with `<MATERIALCONSUMPTIONSECTION>`, the output is incorrect. Something like that: `<POSECTION LOCATION="ABC" />
  <ORDERSECTION SALESORDER="00001" />
  <MATERIALCONSUMPTIONSECTION><MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION DESC="car" QTY="1.000" WORKPLACE="3001_GAT101LH">BIN1000004</MATERIAL_CONSUMPTION></MATERIALCONSUMPTIONSECTION>`

Comment: @HàHoàng: I suggest you to edit your question above, to add more input including the case you want to solve, and providing the output you want.

Comment: @PierreFrançois: i already edited my question above, please help to check it