# XSLT Transformer not showing data

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an xml input file with a transformer in the below link.
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ5g/2

The transformer was created via another developer but now the data is not shown in the output.

Any idea why?? I have been trying to figure this one without luck.

e.g: $root value is not shown in ASSORTMENT_ID or DESCRIPTION tags

Cheers

Comment: Please post your code within your question, not i external links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check, if you a limited to using XSLT 1.0. XSLT 2.0 supports default namespace for XPath. It must look like this:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet  xpath-default-namespace="http://anatwine.com/schema/retailer/api/product" ..... >
```

In case of XSLT 1.0, you need to add the namespace to every element references by XPath. See:

[XSLT Transform doesn't work until I remove root node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node)

Comment: OP's stylesheet says `version="1.0"`. This requires XSLT 2.0 or higher.

Comment: You are right. I've updated the answer.