# xslt node replace then ingest with javascript

Tags: javascript, xslt, nosql, marklogic

I replace in memory XML node based on specific path before ingestion into NoSQL (marklogic) database.

Input: /doc1.xml

```
<image xmlns="http://coin/decimal">
      <DE>
         <denomination>1pf</denomination>
            <reverse>rye stalks</reverse>
            <obverse>oak sprig</obverse>
            <before>Anglo–Saxons</before>
      </DE>
      <GBP>
          <denomination>1p</denomination>
            <reverse>Arms</reverse>
            <obverse>Queen</obverse>
            <before>Anglo–Saxons</before>
      </GBP>
</image>
```

I replace the `/before:image/before:DE/before:before` value to a parameter value
Xsl:

```
const beforeXsl =
 fn.head(xdmp.unquote(
`  <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:before="http://coin/decimal"  version="2.0">
 
    <xsl:template match="/Q{http://coin/decimal}image/Q{http://coin/decimal}DE/Q{http://coin/decimal}before">
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$replace"/>
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
 
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 
  </xsl:transform>
`));
 
xdmp.xsltEval(beforeXsl, doc, params)
```

Expected output:

```
<image xmlns="http://coin/decimal">
      <DE>
         <denomination>1pf</denomination>
            <reverse>rye stalks</reverse>
            <obverse>oak sprig</obverse>
            <before>Anglo-Dutch</before>
      </DE>
      <GBP>
          <denomination>1p</denomination>
            <reverse>Arms</reverse>
            <obverse>Queen</obverse>
            <before>Anglo–Saxons</before>
      </GBP>
</image>
```

I try to parameterize my xsl, but got the error:

```
[javascript] XSLT-BADPATTERN: MarkLogic extension syntax used, EQNames are not supported in XSLT mode
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762628/3016153

Comment: @Mads Hansen and @michael.hor257k, Thanks for the help. - The Qname works in other XSL editor but not in Marklogic.  - I use static EQname because I don’t know other way to pass the path as params. Fiona’s provide that `xdmp:path` is right ON. Now I can pass in the path as params. - She fixes up what I missed: `namespace`. If the sample document is with–different or without namespace then it is transformed incorrectly. I hope I make my points clear. And we are very pleased to see the xslt happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why!   Shouldn’t it have been

```
var params = {};
params.nsProduct = "http://coin/decimal"
params.qPath = "/before:image/before:DE/before:before"
params.replaceValue="Anglo-Dutch"

const implReplace = fn.head(xdmp.unquote(
`
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:before="http://coin/decimal"  
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:param name="nsProduct"/>
    <xsl:param name="qPath"/>
    <xsl:param name="replaceValue" as="xs:anyAtomicType"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()[(xdmp:path(.) eq $qPath)]">
        <xsl:variable name="replace">
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$nsProduct}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$replaceValue"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="$replace"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:transform>

`));

xdmp.xsltEval(implReplace, doc, params)
```

Comment: Ms. Fiona: The answer hits the mark! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

[EQname](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#doc-xquery30-EQName) are not supported in XSLT 2.0 stylesheets. You are attempting to use them in the `@match` expression.

Instead, use the `before` namespace-prefix that you already have defined in the XPath in your `@match` expression in your XSLT:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:before="http://coin/decimal"  version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="replace"/>

  <xsl:template match="/before:image/before:DE/before:before">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$replace"/>
        </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

You will also need to define an `xsl:param` or `xsl:variable` for the `$replace`, which is currently undefined.