# XSLT sort parents by child value changes element arrangements

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following simplified XML:

```
 <Data>
    <DataValue>Data</DataValue>
    <Product>
        <Price>60</Price>
        <Value>Product Value</Value>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Price>50</Price>
        <Value>Product Value</Value>
    </Product>
    <Information>
        <Entry>Some Information Text</Entry>
    </Information>
    <Description>
        <Entry>Some Description Text</Entry>
    </Description>
 </Data>
```

I sort the product elements by the price value, with the following xslt code:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Data']">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(local-name()='Product')]"/>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name()='Product']" >   
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="*[local-name()='Price']/text()" order="ascending"/>                            
        </xsl:apply-templates>  
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Which leads to the following wrong result:

```
<Data>
   <DataValue>Data</DataValue>
   <Information>
      <Entry>Some Information Text</Entry>
   </Information>
   <Description>
      <Entry>Some Description Text</Entry>
   </Description>
   <Product>
      <Price>50</Price>
      <Value>Product Value</Value>
   </Product>
   <Product>
      <Price>60</Price>
      <Value>Product Value</Value>
   </Product>
</Data>
```

The problem now is that the correctly sorted "Products" elements are placed at the end after the transformation. Is there a way to sort only parts of an xml while the other elements remain untouched and also remain on the same places?

Comment: Are you saying that if the order of elements was `Information, Product, Description, Product, DataValue`, then sort the products might swap the two products while leaving the order otherwise unchanged?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution to my question was the following

**Input**

```
 <Data>
   <DataValue>Data</DataValue>
   <Product>
    <Price>60</Price>
    <Value>Product Value 2</Value>
   </Product>
   <Product>
    <Price>50</Price>
    <Value>Product Value 1</Value>
   </Product>    
   <Information>
     <Entry>Some Information Text</Entry>
   </Information>
   <Description>
     <Entry>Some Description Text</Entry>
   </Description>
 </Data>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
     <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Product' and ./*[local-name()='Price']]">
    <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()='Product']) = 0">
        <xsl:for-each select="../*[local-name()='Product']">
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="./*[local-name() = 'Price']/text()" order="ascending"/>                
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>   
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```
<Data>
   <DataValue>Data</DataValue>
   <Product>
      <Price>50</Price>
      <Value>Product Value 1</Value>
   </Product>
   <Product>
      <Price>60</Price>
      <Value>Product Value 2</Value>
   </Product>
   <Information>
      <Entry>Some Information Text</Entry>
   </Information>
   <Description>
      <Entry>Some Description Text</Entry>
   </Description>
</Data>
```

The product is sorted by price in ascending order, the rest of the XML structure remains untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="DataValue"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Product">
            <xsl:sort select="Price" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Information | Description"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. There should never be a need to use a hack like `*[local-name()='xyz']`. If your input uses namespaces, deal with them properly - see here how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762628/3016153