# How to convert Tesseract software output (hocr) into plain txt file with fop (generates zero output)?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, apache-fop, hocr

**The resulting output:** a txt file with empty lines.

**The expected output:** a txt file with words of "Привет Мир! Это я, обычный неработающий текст или рыба" text.

What am I doing wrong? Tried nested xsl:for-each code gives out the same kind of behavior.

Comment: It is the usual FAQ problem of the input having a default namespace sest up that is in scope for all descendants so the `div` and `span` elements are in the XHTML namespace while your XSLT/XPath 1.0 attempt tries to select `div` or `span` elements in no namespace. Easy fix exists in XSLT 2 or 3 declaring `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on the `xsl:stylesheet`. Needs an XSLT 2 or 3 processor like Saxon 9, 10 or 11, available in the context of Java FOP without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 problems in your attempt:

1. Your instruction:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="//div [@class='ocr_page'] /div [@class='ocr_carea'] / p [@class='ocr_par'] / span[@class='ocr_line'] / span [@class='ocrx_word']">
   ```

   selects nothing, because your input XML puts all its elements in a
   namespace. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762628/3016153) how to solve this.
2. Once you have it working, this instruction will put you in the
   context of `span`. From this context, your next instruction:

   ```
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(span [@class='ocrx_word'])" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
   ```

   also selects nothing, because `span` is not a child of itself. It
   should be:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
   ```

   and I doubt you want to disable output escaping in a stylesheet
   producing an XML result.

Comment: I understand the second problem and corrected it. Could you, @michael.hor257k please explain this problem more clearlier than in your's link?

Comment: Not sure what's not clear: add say `xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` to your `xsl:stylesheet` start tag, then add the `x:` prefix to all element names in your XPath expression.