# Xslt remove attribut and element in xml response not found

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I need your help to modify an xml by deleting elements and attributes
the modification I'm making can't reach the elements
here my base xml

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xml:base="https://urldebas.com">
    <id>https://urldebas.com</id>
    <title type="text">value</title>
    <updated>2022-10-12T17:11:09Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name/>
    </author>
    <link href="EQUIPMENTSet" rel="self" title="EQUIPMENTSet"/>
    <entry>
        <id>https://urldebas.com</id>
        <title type="text">EQUIPMENTSet(Plant='1268',EquipmentID='10042621')</title>
        <updated>2022-10-12T17:11:09Z</updated>
        <category term="ZPM_MASTER_DATA_SRV.EQUIPMENT" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
        <link href="EQUIPMENTSet(Plant='1268',EquipmentID='10042621')" rel="self" title="EQUIPMENT"/>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
                <d:Plant>1268</d:Plant>
                <d:EquipmentID>10042621</d:EquipmentID>
                <d:DateOfLastChange>2021-05-03T00:00:00</d:DateOfLastChange>
                <d:Description>AEROTHERME No1</d:Description>
                <d:FunctionalLocation>FR29-1268-BA70-AERG</d:FunctionalLocation>
                <d:MainWorkCenter>PM1268SG</d:MainWorkCenter>
                <d:CostCenter>BE01G001</d:CostCenter>
                <d:SortField>AEROTHERME 1</d:SortField>
                <d:ObjectType></d:ObjectType>
                <d:WorkCenter></d:WorkCenter>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I want to delete
the `xml:base` attribute in feed
the `id` element in **feed and in entry** to get this xml

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
<title type="text">value</title>
<updated>2022-10-12T17:11:09Z</updated>
<author>
    <name />
</author>
<link href="EQUIPMENTSet" rel="self" title="EQUIPMENTSet" />
<entry>
    <title type="text">EQUIPMENTSet(Plant='1268',EquipmentID='10042621')</title>
    <updated>2022-10-12T17:11:09Z</updated>
    <category term="ZPM_MASTER_DATA_SRV.EQUIPMENT" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link href="EQUIPMENTSet(Plant='1268',EquipmentID='10042621')" rel="self" title="EQUIPMENT" />
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
            <d:Plant>1268</d:Plant>
            <d:EquipmentID>10042621</d:EquipmentID>
            <d:DateOfLastChange>2021-05-03T00:00:00</d:DateOfLastChange>
            <d:Description>AEROTHERME No1</d:Description>
            <d:FunctionalLocation>FR29-1268-BA70-AERG</d:FunctionalLocation>
            <d:MainWorkCenter>PM1268SG</d:MainWorkCenter>
            <d:CostCenter>BE01G001</d:CostCenter>
            <d:SortField>AEROTHERME 1</d:SortField>
            <d:ObjectType></d:ObjectType>
            <d:WorkCenter></d:WorkCenter>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

My Xslt file

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@xml:base"/>
<xsl:template match="feed/id"/>
<xsl:template match="feed/entry/id"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add (1) your current XSLT and (2) the expected result.

Comment: You have namespace issues - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762628/3016153

Comment: Sorry but it don't know how fix it in my case . I will try and give you back

Answer (score 0):

Note that your source document contains a default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"` which means that unprefixed element names in the document (including the `feed`, `entry`, and `id` elements) are in the namespace whose identifier is `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` (Note also that the default namespace applies to elements but does not apply to attributes; an unprefixed attribute name is always in the empty namespace).

So to refer to the Atom elements in your XSLT you will need to declare the Atom namespace in your stylesheet, and associate it with a prefix, and then use that prefix in your XPath expressions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@xml:base"/>
    <xsl:template match="atom:feed/atom:id"/>
    <xsl:template match="atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:id"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```