# XSLT help grouping or matching nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have this XML, that is a series of ContactInfo nodes, some contain the PostAddr, and some contain the PhoneNum.
I have to match the ContactInfo node that contains the address with the one that contains the PhoneNum like this - the AddrSource tag value (in the ContactInfo nodes that contain address) should match the PhoneNum Source attribute value(from the ContactInfo nodes that contain phones).

This is a sample of the XML:

```
<ContactInfo Source="MB" EffDt="2022-10-11">
        <PostAddr>
            <StreetNum>xxx</StreetNum>
            <StreetName>ATLANTA</StreetName>
            <StreetType>HWY</StreetType>
            <Apt>099</Apt>
            <City>MONTGOMERY</City>
            <StateProv>AL</StateProv>
            <PostalCode>1000</PostalCode>
            <County>MONTGOMERY</County>
            <AddrType>S</AddrType>
            <ReportedDt>2019-08-09</ReportedDt>
            <AddrSource>3</AddrSource>
            <AddrCreatedDt>2019-07-22</AddrCreatedDt>
        </PostAddr>
    </ContactInfo>
    <ContactInfo Source="MB" EffDt="2022-10-11">
        <PostAddr>
            <StreetNum>09521</StreetNum>
            <StreetName>STANTON</StreetName>
            <StreetType>WAY</StreetType>
            <Apt>APT 19080</Apt>
            <City>PRATTVILLE</City>
            <StateProv>AL</StateProv>
            <PostalCode>111-111</PostalCode>
            <County>AUTAUGA</County>
            <AddrType>H</AddrType>
            <ReportedDt>2019-04-09</ReportedDt>
            <AddrSource>4</AddrSource>
            <AddrCreatedDt>2019-04-03</AddrCreatedDt>
        </PostAddr>
    </ContactInfo>
    <ContactInfo Source="MB" EffDt="2022-10-11">
        <PhoneNum Source="3" EffDt="2022-10-11">
            <PhoneType>OTHER   </PhoneType>
            <Phone>123224434</Phone>
        </PhoneNum>
    </ContactInfo>
    <ContactInfo Source="MB" EffDt="2022-10-11">
        <PhoneNum Source="4" EffDt="2022-10-11">
            <PhoneType>OTHER   /WIRELESS</PhoneType>
            <Phone>30000</Phone>
        </PhoneNum>
    </ContactInfo>
```

Ultimately I need to be able to make a table in this format:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What should be my approach here? I have been mainly working with for-each loops and choose but I can't seem to find a way to make them work here. I looked a bit into grouping but I wasn't able to apply that either, so I'm a bit stuck with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT has a built-in [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) mechanism for resolving cross-references. Here's a minimal example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="phone" match="PhoneNum" use="@Source" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="ContactInfo/PostAddr">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('phone', AddrSource)/Phone"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example - after adding a root element! - this will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>MONTGOMERY</td>
      <td>123224434</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>PRATTVILLE</td>
      <td>30000</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: does key also work if I have namespaces? for example if I have <xsl:key name="phone" match="ds:PhoneNum" use="@Source" />

Comment: Yes. Provided you declare the namespace - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762628/3016153.

Comment: thanks. can I associate 2 phone numbers to one address with this approach?

Comment: Yes. The expression `key('phone', AddrSource)` selects all related phone numbers. What you do with it depends on the exact result you want to get (your question does not say).

Comment: god bless you. helped me a lot.