# Cannot match xml nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am writing a basic xslt program. I cannot get to select the nodes i want. I am targetting to see /Events/Event/System/Computer

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
      <h2>Event</h2>  
        <table>
            <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>  
            </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Event">
        <td><xsl:apply-templates select="System"/> </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="System">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Computer"/> 
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="Computer">
      Computer: <span style="color:#ff0000">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
      <br />
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Above is my style sheet, I am trying to print computer value on a loop.
In my example XML below, what is required is to print the computer name twice.

```
XML code
---------
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Events>
    <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
        <System>
            <Provider Name='Application Error'/>
            <EventID Qualifiers='0'>1000</EventID>
            <Version>0</Version>
            <Level>2</Level>
            <Task>100</Task>
            <Opcode>0</Opcode>
            <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
            <TimeCreated SystemTime='2023-01-11T10:22:54.9821986Z'/>
            <EventRecordID>85280</EventRecordID>
            <Correlation/>
            <Execution ProcessID='0' ThreadID='0'/>
            <Channel>Application</Channel>
            <Computer>Peru-Desktop</Computer>
            <Security/>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data>RuntimeBroker.exe</Data>
            <Data>10.0.19041.746</Data>
            <Data>5b78739c</Data>
            <Data>ntdll.dll</Data>
            <Data>10.0.19041.2130</Data>
            <Data>b5ced1c6</Data>
            <Data>c0000374</Data>
            <Data>00000000000ff6a9</Data>
            <Data>28c0</Data>
            <Data>01d9259e77eefd6c</Data>
            <Data>C:\Windows\System32\RuntimeBroker.exe</Data>
            <Data>C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll</Data>
            <Data>66a01ef8-5dc9-4305-8670-d39ef7144aaf</Data>
            <Data>Microsoft.Windows.Search_1.14.7.19041_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy</Data>
            <Data>runtimebroker07f4358a809ac99a64a67c1</Data>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
    <Event
        xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
        <System>
            <Provider Name='Application Error'/>
            <EventID Qualifiers='0'>1000</EventID>
            <Version>0</Version>
            <Level>2</Level>
            <Task>100</Task>
            <Opcode>0</Opcode>
            <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
            <TimeCreated SystemTime='2023-01-11T05:17:35.3925442Z'/>
            <EventRecordID>85258</EventRecordID>
            <Correlation/>
            <Execution ProcessID='0' ThreadID='0'/>
            <Channel>Application</Channel>
            <Computer>Peru-Desktop</Computer>
            <Security/>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data>ftnlsv.exe</Data>
            <Data>3.3.10.0</Data>
            <Data>5fa14984</Data>
            <Data>ntdll.dll</Data>
            <Data>10.0.19041.2130</Data>
            <Data>b5ced1c6</Data>
            <Data>c0000409</Data>
            <Data>000000000008c67f</Data>
            <Data>15bc</Data>
            <Data>01d925799d1bd691</Data>
            <Data>C:\Program Files\Common Files\VMware\DeviceRedirectionCommon\ftnlsv.exe</Data>
            <Data>C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll</Data>
            <Data>96b01680-a7d7-4e54-b2a8-b350ed24498d</Data>
            <Data></Data>
            <Data></Data>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
</Events>`
```

Currently I print everything including  and all values under Event, This is not what i was wondering.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Event</h2>
      <table>
         <tr><td>Computer: <span style="color:#ff0000">Peru-Desktop</span><br /></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Computer: <span style="color:#ff0000">Peru-Desktop</span><br /></td></tr>
</table></body></html>`
```

Comment: Do note that `Events` is not in a namespace, while all other elements are.

Comment: So what should be done? Should i have to add name space somewhere to treat it the same?

Comment: Have you read the answer in the link above? You need to add a prefix to every reference to any element in the input XML except `Events`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node

This helped me in resolving the issue. Thanks to @michael.hor257k