# XLS Transformation - Ignore Namespace. Keep as XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this input xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <out:ServiceResponse xmlns:out="http://test.me/datatypes">
        <out:Parties>
            <out:Party>
                <out:Field1>Value1</out:Field1>
                <out:Field2>Value2</out:Field2>
            </out:Party>
        </out:Parties>
    </out:ServiceResponse>
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this XSLT defined:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='elementName']">
    <Entities>
        <xResults>
            <xsl:for-each select="ServiceResponse/Parties/Party">
                <aParty>
                    <Field1Transformed>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Field1"/>
                    </Field1Transformed>
                    <Field2Transformed>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Field2"/>
                    </Field2Transformed>
                </aParty>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xResults>
    </Entities>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when it is applied the output is a html instead of the required xml.

For my use case I need to ignore the namespaces. I can't reference "out:" or any form of placeholder over and over again.

Many thanks.

Comment: The template match in your XSLT has the strategy you would want to apply (matching on the local-name()), however it looks like this was an example/shell given as an example and you haven't replaced "elementName" with "Body". Do that, and then make similar updates to the XPaths inside of the template, matching on any element `*` and then applying the predicate filter on the `local-name()`.

Comment: Thank you @MadsHansen, this works. But I was hoping to find a way where I dont have to update all the XPaths. I actually have a  large existing XSLT that I am trying to update to be more generic; I'm looking for a shortcut so I dont have to update all the existing xpaths. :(

Comment: So, what you really want is to remove the namespaces from the elements? Do you want to maintain the same `local-name()`? If so, then why post an XSLT that isn't doing that, and that doesn't even work?

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 or higher you can declare `xpath-default-namespace` once and use the  local name in all your XPath expressions that refer to nodes in that namespace. In XSLT 1.0 you have no choice but to adjust XPath expressions that use the local name for nodes that are in a namespace. And I would strongly recommend you adjust them by [adding a prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762628/3016153) instead of the  `*[local-name()='elementName']` hack that ignores namespaces and will bite you when two elements in different namespaces share the same local name.

Comment: P.S. *"But when it is applied the output is a html instead of the required xml."* That makes no sense and cannot be true.

Comment: Correction: Actually, you do have a choice: you could perform the transformation in two passes: first, move all nodes in a namespace to no-namespace; then transform the result using local names only. But this has the same flaw as the other method.

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback. It is all very useful.