# How to traverse in XSLT to get a node value with root node having namespace?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Below is the XML and XSLT I am using and what I am trying to traverse and retrieve:

```
<Request xmlns="http://tempuri.org/cXML" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Id="d92e1d78-5a8e-4a76-b013-e4519c66dd54">
    <OrderRequest>
        <OrderRequestHeader orderID="11-213F6F" orderDate="09/6/2023 11:20:55 AM">
            <Total>
                <Money currency="USD">0.00</Money>
            </Total>
            <BillTo>
                <Address>
                    <Name xml:lang="en-us"/>
                    <PostalAddress name="">
                        <Street/>
                        <City/>
                        <State/>
                        <PostalCode/>
                    </PostalAddress>
                </Address>
            </BillTo>
            <Contact role="customerService">
                <Name xml:lang="en-us"/>
                <Email/>
                <Phone name="Office">
                    <TelephoneNumber>
                        <AreaOrCityCode/>
                        <Number/>
                    </TelephoneNumber>
                </Phone>
            </Contact>
        </OrderRequestHeader>
        <ItemOut quantity="1" lineNumber="001">
            <ItemID>
                <SupplierPartID>TEST1</SupplierPartID>
                <BuyerPartID>TEST1</BuyerPartID>
            </ItemID>
            <ItemDetail>
                <UnitPrice>
                    <Money currency="USD">0.0000</Money>
                </UnitPrice>
                <Description xml:lang="en-us"/>
                <UnitOfMeasure/>
                <URL/>
                <Extrinsic name="SKU">TEST1-001</Extrinsic>
            </ItemDetail>
            <ShipTo>
                <Address>
                    <PostalAddress name="">
                        <DeliverTo/>
                        <DeliverTo/>
                        <Street/>
                        <Street/>
                        <Street/>
                        <Street/>
                        <City/>
                        <State/>
                        <PostalCode/>
                    </PostalAddress>
                </Address>
            </ShipTo>
            <Shipping>
                <Description>FedEx Ground</Description>
            </Shipping>
        </ItemOut>
        <ItemOut quantity="1" lineNumber="002">
            <ItemID>
                <SupplierPartID>TEST2</SupplierPartID>
                <BuyerPartID>TEST2</BuyerPartID>
            </ItemID>
            <ItemDetail>
                <UnitPrice>
                    <Money currency="USD">0.0000</Money>
                </UnitPrice>
                <Description xml:lang="en-us"/>
                <UnitOfMeasure/>
                <URL/>
                <Extrinsic name="SKU">TEST2-002</Extrinsic>
            </ItemDetail>
            <ShipTo>
                <Address>
                    <PostalAddress name="">
                        <DeliverTo/>
                        <DeliverTo/>
                        <Street/>
                        <Street/>
                        <Street/>
                        <Street/>
                        <City/>
                        <State/>
                        <PostalCode/>
                    </PostalAddress>
                </Address>
            </ShipTo>
            <Shipping>
                <Description>FedEx Ground</Description>
            </Shipping>
        </ItemOut>
    </OrderRequest>
</Request>
```

for the above xml I need to retrieve one of the Shipping/Description.
given that the root node "Request" has namespace when I use xsl:value-of it is returning nothing

here is the XSLT i am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:cxml="http://tempuri.org/cXML" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn dbd" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <AssignOrderRequest>
            <SenderID>TESTER</SenderID>
            <ReceiverID>LLC</ReceiverID>
            <ClientAddress>test-1101-202</ClientAddress>
            <AssignOrder>
                <AssignmentNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select=".//cxml:OrderRequestHeader/@orderID"/>
                </AssignmentNumber>
                <AssignmentDate>
                    <xsl:value-of select=".//cxml:OrderRequestHeader/@orderDate"/>
                </AssignmentDate>
                <OrderCount>1</OrderCount>
                <SalesOrder>
                    <Received>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.//cxml:OrderRequestHeader/@orderDate,0,11)"/>
                    </Received>
                    <Requested>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.//cxml:OrderRequestHeader/@orderDate,0,11)"/>
                    </Requested>
                    <CustomerPO>
                        <xsl:value-of select=".//cxml:OrderRequestHeader/@orderID"/>
                    </CustomerPO>
                    <CustomerPODate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.//cxml:OrderRequestHeader/@orderDate,0,11)"/>
                    </CustomerPODate>
                    <ShipMethod>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*/ItemOut[1]/Shipping/Description"/>
                    </ShipMethod>
                    <BillFreight>
                        <Type>3</Type>
                        <Name/>
                        <Address>
                            <Street/>
                            <Street2/>
                            <City/>
                            <Region/>
                            <PostalCode/>
                            <Country/>
                            <Type/>
                        </Address>
                        <Account>
                            <Type>F</Type>
                            <Code>123568944</Code>
                        </Account>
                    </BillFreight>
                    <Total/>
                    <Customer>
                        <ID>04123</ID>
                        <Billing>
                            <Name>LLC</Name>
                            <Address>
                                <Street/>
                                <Street2/>
                                <City/>
                                <Region/>
                                <PostalCode/>
                            </Address>
                        </Billing>
                        <ShipTo>
                            <Name/>
                            <Address>
                                <Street/>
                                <Street2/>
                                <Street3/>
                                <City/>
                                <Region/>
                                <PostalCode/>
                                <Type/>
                            </Address>
                        </ShipTo>
                    </Customer>
                    <CommentData>
                        <Comment>
                            <xsl:value-of select=".//cxml:ItemOut/ShipTo/Address/PostalAddress/DeliverTo"/>
                        </Comment>
                        <Internal>TRUE</Internal>
                    </CommentData>
                    <xsl:for-each select=".//cxml:ItemOut">
                        <SalesOrderDetail>
                            <Line>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@lineNumber"/>
                            </Line>
                            <Type>D</Type>
                            <SkuNbr>
                                <xsl:value-of select=".//cxml:Extrinsic[@name='SKU']"/>
                            </SkuNbr>
                            <TotalQuantity>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@quantity"/>
                            </TotalQuantity>
                            <TotalPrice>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@quantity * .//cxml:Money"/>
                            </TotalPrice>
                        </SalesOrderDetail>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </SalesOrder>
            </AssignOrder>
        </AssignOrderRequest>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So ShipMethod in XSL transformation code is not returning anything
`<xsl:value-of select="*/ItemOut[1]/Shipping/Description"/>`

what is the right way to get one of the ItemOut/Shipping/Description ?

I tried a couple different ways to get Request/OrderRequest/ItemOut/Shipping/Description value in XSLT code and nothing worked for me.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69432328/3016153

Comment: @michael.hor257k that really helped.
I used this to retrieve the node and it worked fine
<xsl:value-of select="cxml:Request/cxml:OrderRequest/cxml:ItemOut[1]/cxml:Shipping/cxml:Description" />

Comment: I am afraid you missed the point of the other answer: in XSLT 2.0 you can declare `xpath-default-namespace` and get rid of the prefixes.