# XML values to be extracted

Tags: xml, xslt, extract

I need to extract the values which are between the `<bl>` and `</bl>` and always belong to the value before it. eg Fabrikat: Honda, Type: Roadrunner and so on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<onlv xmlns="http://www.oenorm.at/schema/A2063/2021-03-01">
  <metadaten></metadaten>
  <grafiktabelle></grafiktabelle>
  <leistungsteiltabelle></leistungsteiltabelle>
  <zztabelle></zztabelle>
  <akztabelle></akztabelle>
  <zugelassenenachlaesse></zugelassenenachlaesse>
  <ausschreibungs-lv>
    <gliederung-og>
    <og-liste>
      <og nr="01">
      <og-eigenschaften></og-eigenschaften>
      <lb></lb>
      <svb></svb>
      <lg-liste>
        <lg nr="01">
        <lg-eigenschaften></lg-eigenschaften>
          <ulg-liste>
            <ulg nr="01">
              <ulg-eigenschaften></ulg-eigenschaften>
              <positionen>
                <grundtextnr nr="01">
                  <ungeteilteposition mfv="">
                    <pos-eigenschaften>
                      <stichwort>Fleischwolf</stichwort>
                      <langtext><p>Fabrikat: <bl>Honda</bl></p><p>Type: <bl>Roadrunner</bl></p><p>Preis: <bl>12580.00</bl> EUR</p>
                      </langtext>
                      <einheit>Stk</einheit>
                      <pzzv>
                        <normalposition></normalposition>
                      </pzzv>
                      <leistungsteil>1</leistungsteil>
                      <lvmenge>1</lvmenge>
                      <nichtangeboten></nichtangeboten>
                    </pos-eigenschaften>
                  </ungeteilteposition>
                </grundtextnr>
                <grundtextnr nr="02">
                  <ungeteilteposition mfv="">
                    <pos-eigenschaften>
                      <stichwort>Induktionsherd</stichwort>
                      <langtext><p>Fabrikat: <bl>BMW</bl></p><p>Type: <bl>GS1250</bl></p><p>Preis: <bl>22870.00</bl> EUR</p>
                      </langtext>
                      <einheit>Stk</einheit>
                      <pzzv>
                        <normalposition></normalposition>
                      </pzzv>
                      <leistungsteil>1</leistungsteil>
                      <lvmenge>1</lvmenge>
                      <nichtangeboten></nichtangeboten>
                    </pos-eigenschaften>
                  </ungeteilteposition>
                </grundtextnr>
                <grundtextnr nr="03">
                  <ungeteilteposition mfv="">
                    <pos-eigenschaften>
                      <stichwort>Kühlwanne</stichwort>
                      <langtext><p>Fabrikat: <bl>Harley Davidson</bl></p><p>Type: <bl>Bigfoot</bl></p><p>Preis: <bl>28756.00</bl> EUR</p>
                      </langtext>
                      <einheit>Stk</einheit>
                      <pzzv>
                        <normalposition></normalposition>
                      </pzzv>
                      <wesentlicheposition>W</wesentlicheposition>
                      <leistungsteil>1</leistungsteil>
                      <lvmenge>1</lvmenge>
                      <nichtangeboten></nichtangeboten>
                    </pos-eigenschaften>
                  </ungeteilteposition>
                </grundtextnr>
                <grundtextnr nr="04">
                  <ungeteilteposition mfv="">
                    <pos-eigenschaften>
                      <stichwort>Kaffeemaschine (Vollautomat)</stichwort>
                      <langtext><p>Fabrikat: <bl>Franke</bl></p><p>Type: <bl>GrossUndGut</bl></p><p>Preis: <bl>18000.00</bl> EUR</p>
                      </langtext>
                      <einheit>Stk</einheit>
                      <pzzv>
                        <eventualposition></eventualposition>
                      </pzzv>
                      <leistungsteil>1</leistungsteil>
                      <lvmenge>1</lvmenge>
                      <nichtangeboten></nichtangeboten>
                    </pos-eigenschaften>
                  </ungeteilteposition>
                </grundtextnr>
              </positionen>
            </ulg>
            <ulg nr="02">
              <ulg-eigenschaften></ulg-eigenschaften>
              <positionen>
                <grundtextnr nr="01">
                  <ungeteilteposition mfv="">
                    <pos-eigenschaften>
                      <stichwort>Maschine 4</stichwort>
                      <langtext><p>Fabrikat: <bl>DELL</bl></p><p>Type: <bl>XPS</bl></p><p>Preis: <bl>1280.00</bl> EUR</p>
                      </langtext>
                      <einheit>Stk</einheit>
                      <pzzv>
                        <normalposition></normalposition>
                      </pzzv>
                      <leistungsteil>1</leistungsteil>
                      <lvmenge>1</lvmenge>
                      <nichtangeboten></nichtangeboten>
                    </pos-eigenschaften>
                  </ungeteilteposition>
                </grundtextnr>
                <grundtextnr nr="02">
                  <ungeteilteposition mfv="">
                    <pos-eigenschaften>
                      <stichwort>Maschine 5</stichwort>
                      <langtext><p>Fabrikat: <bl>HP</bl></p><p>Type: <bl>12345</bl></p><p>Preis: <bl>1890.00</bl> EUR</p>
                      </langtext>
                      <einheit>Stk</einheit>
                      <pzzv>
                        <normalposition></normalposition>
                      </pzzv>
                      <leistungsteil>1</leistungsteil>
                      <lvmenge>1</lvmenge>
                      <nichtangeboten></nichtangeboten>
                    </pos-eigenschaften>
                  </ungeteilteposition>
                </grundtextnr>
              </positionen>
            </ulg>
          </ulg-liste>
        </lg>
        <lg nr="02">
        <lg-eigenschaften></lg-eigenschaften>
          <ulg-liste>
            <ulg nr="01">
              <ulg-eigenschaften></ulg-eigenschaften>
              <positionen>
                <grundtextnr nr="01">
                  <ungeteilteposition mfv="">
                    <pos-eigenschaften>
                      <stichwort>Maschine 6</stichwort>
                      <langtext><p>Fabrikat: <bl>Sony</bl></p><p>Type: <bl>Workstation</bl></p><p>Preis: <bl>2500.00</bl> EUR</p>
                      </langtext>
                      <einheit>Stk</einheit>
                      <pzzv>
                        <normalposition></normalposition>
                      </pzzv>
                      <leistungsteil>1</leistungsteil>
                      <lvmenge>1</lvmenge>
                      <nichtangeboten></nichtangeboten>
                    </pos-eigenschaften>
                  </ungeteilteposition>
                </grundtextnr>
              </positionen>
            </ulg>
            <ulg nr="02">
              <ulg-eigenschaften></ulg-eigenschaften>
              <positionen>
                <grundtextnr nr="01">
                  <ungeteilteposition mfv="">
                    <pos-eigenschaften>
                      <stichwort>Maschine 7</stichwort>
                      <langtext><p>Fabrikat: <bl>ACER</bl></p><p>Type: <bl>123</bl></p><p>Preis: <bl>1280.00</bl> EUR</p>
                      </langtext>
                      <einheit>Stk</einheit>
                      <pzzv>
                        <normalposition>
                        </normalposition>
                      </pzzv>
                      <leistungsteil>1</leistungsteil>
                      <lvmenge>1</lvmenge>
                      <nichtangeboten></nichtangeboten>
                    </pos-eigenschaften>
                  </ungeteilteposition>
                </grundtextnr>
              </positionen>
            </ulg>
          </ulg-liste>
        </lg>
      </lg-liste>
      </og>
    </og-liste>
    </gliederung-og>
  </ausschreibungs-lv>
</onlv>
```

In a [former post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77258631/import-just-a-part-of-a-xml) I got a solution for the draft which was valid by then. But the draft changed. So I tried to alter it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:oen="http://www.oenorm.at/schema/A2063/2021-03-01"
exclude-result-prefixes="oen">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <dataroot>
    <xsl:variable select=".//oen:og-liste">
      <xsl:for-each select=".//oen:og">
        <xsl:variable select="following-sibling::oen:lg-liste[1]">
          <xsl:variable select=".//oen:lg">
            <xsl:variable select=".//oen:ulg-liste[1]">
              <xsl:for-each select=".//oen:ulg">
                <xsl:for-each select=".//oen:grundtextnr">
                  <xsl:for-each select=".//oen:langtext/oen:p">
                    <onlv>
                      <p>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ':')"/>
                      </p>
                      <bl>
                        <xsl:value-of select="oen:bl"/>
                      </bl>
                    </onlv>
                  </xsl:for-each> 
                </xsl:for-each> 
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
          </xsl:variable>
        </xsl:variable>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    </dataroot>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There is so much code to explain the complete hierarchy. What I need is shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2023-10-27T10:02:32">
<bl>
<og>01</og>
<lg>01</lg>
<ulg>01</ulg>
<grundtextnr>01</grundtextnr>
<fabrikat>Honda</fabrikat>
<type>Roadrunner</type>
<preis>12580,00</preis>
</bl>
<bl>
<og>01</og>
<lg>01</lg>
<ulg>01</ulg>
<grundtextnr>02</grundtextnr>
<fabrikat>BMW</fabrikat>
<type>GS1250</type>
<preis>22870,00</preis>
</bl>
<bl>
<og>01</og>
<lg>01</lg>
<ulg>01</ulg>
<grundtextnr>03</grundtextnr>
<fabrikat>Harley Davidson</fabrikat>
<type>Bigfoot</type>
<preis>28756,00</preis>
</bl>
<bl>
<og>01</og>
<lg>01</lg>
<ulg>01</ulg>
<grundtextnr>04</grundtextnr>
<fabrikat>Franke</fabrikat>
<type>GrossUndGut</type>
<preis>18000,00</preis>
</bl>
<bl>
<og>01</og>
<lg>01</lg>
<ulg>02</ulg>
<grundtextnr>01</grundtextnr>
<fabrikat>Dell</fabrikat>
<type>XPS</type>
<preis>1280,00</preis>
</bl>
<bl>
<og>01</og>
<lg>01</lg>
<ulg>02</ulg>
<grundtextnr>02</grundtextnr>
<fabrikat>HP</fabrikat>
<type>12345</type>
<preis>1890,00</preis>
</bl>
<bl>
<og>01</og>
<lg>02</lg>
<ulg>01</ulg>
<grundtextnr>01</grundtextnr>
<fabrikat>Sony</fabrikat>
<type>Workstation</type>
<preis>2500,00</preis>
</bl>
<bl>
<og>01</og>
<lg>02</lg>
<ulg>02</ulg>
<grundtextnr>01</grundtextnr>
<fabrikat>Acer</fabrikat>
<type>123</type>
<preis>1280,00</preis>
</bl>
</dataroot>
```

Comment: You are closing the variables at the wrong point. The reason for creating those variables at the ancestor level is to avoid having to go up the tree from each descendant to get the ancestor's value.

Answer (score 0):

I am once again mostly guessing here, but it seems to me you want to do something like this (using XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:oen="http://www.oenorm.at/schema/A2063/2021-03-01"
exclude-result-prefixes="oen">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <dataroot>
        <xsl:for-each select="//oen:og">
            <xsl:variable name="og" select="@nr"/>
            <xsl:for-each select=".//oen:lg">
                <xsl:variable name="lg" select="@nr"/>
                <xsl:for-each select=".//oen:ulg">
                    <xsl:variable name="ulg" select="@nr"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select=".//oen:grundtextnr">
                        <bl>
                            <og>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$og"/>
                            </og>
                            <lg>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$lg"/>
                            </lg>
                            <ulg>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$ulg"/>
                            </ulg>
                            <grundtextnr>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@nr"/>
                            </grundtextnr>
                            <xsl:for-each select=".//oen:langtext/oen:p">
                                <xsl:element name="{substring-before(., ':')}">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="oen:bl"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </bl>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </dataroot>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the redesign of the code. As I don´t want to be impolite: please tell me what you are missing/why our are guessing.

Comment: At no point did you explain the logic of the required  transformation. So I need to guess, for example: do we know in advance which values are included in  `langtext`? Perhaps we should extract the `Fabrikat` value specifically by its name? And that's just one example.