# XSLT matching xhtml namespace

Tags: xslt, xhtml, xml-namespaces

Good day,

I'm trying to match the 'head' element in an xhtml file produced from an html file with the [HTML tidy markup corrector](https://www.html-tidy.org/) using this command line:

```
tidy -asxml -output test_tidy.html --numeric-entities yes .\test.html
```

test_tidy.html contains the following xmlns namespace:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
```

This XSLT template match doesn't work for me:

```
<xsl:template match="//head">
```

What am I missing?
Ideally I want to use the same stylesheet for processing XHTML files with or without the xmlns namespace declaration, for example to process this file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
               <head>
```

Any help gratefully received.

Best wishes!

Comment: *All* XHTML documents are in the XHTML namespace. See here how to handle it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node

Comment: Of course that answer is slightly out of date. A search for "XSLT default namespace" today finds 806 answers.

Comment: @MichaelKay What can be learned from those 806 answers that isn't already contained in the **two** answers in the provided link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the same template to match the `head` element in both:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
```

and:

```
<html>
     <head>
```

you must make your template:

```
<xsl:template match="x:head|head">
```

after declaring `xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`.

---

Alternatively, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='head']">
```

or (in XSLT 2.0 or higher):

```
<xsl:template match="*:head">
```

but that's generally not good practice as (at least in theory) there could be other `head` elements in other namespaces that you do not want to match.

Comment: Thank you for your incredibly comprehensive answer, so much information in so few words! All is now completely clear to me.