# How to use XSLT to transform a XML to XML

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I don't know where I'm missing but... I have this XML:

```
<Records xmlns=http://www.archer-tech.com/ xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:schemaLocation=https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/schema/2.0/archerapi https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/resource/2.0/archerreport.xsd>
<Record>
<app_name>C3L-SCHEDULER</app_name>
<app_id>1484475</app_id>
<cwe_description>testsdsasadas</cwe_description>
</Record>
<Record>
<app_name>C3L-SCHEDULER</app_name>
<app_id>1484475</app_id>
</Record>
<Record>
<app_name>C3L-SCHEDULER</app_name>
<app_id>1484475</app_id>
<cwe_description>testsdsasadsadasdsadaas</cwe_description>
</Record>
</Records>
```

I already tried to do this, using xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl=http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform>
<xsl:output method="xml" input="xml" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<Records>
<xsl:for-each select="./Record">
<Record>
<xsl:copy-of select="app_name" />
<app_id><xsl:value-of select="app_id" /></app_id>
<cwe_description>
<xsl:if test="cwe_description">
<xsl:copy-of select="cwe_description" />
</xsl:if>
</cwe_description>
</Record>
</xsl:for-each>
</Records>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am expecting a XML like this:

```
<Records>
<Record>
<app_name>C3L-SCHEDULER</app_name>
<app_id>1484475</app_id>
<cwe_description>testsdsasadas</cwe_description>
</Record>
<Record>
<app_name>C3L-SCHEDULER</app_name>
<app_id>1484475</app_id>
<cwe_description></cwe_description>
</Record>
<Record>
<app_name>C3L-SCHEDULER</app_name>
<app_id>1484475</app_id>
<cwe_description>testsdsasadsadasdsadaas</cwe_description>
</Record>
</Records>
```

It's working, but I'm receiving a translated XML:

How to solve it? Do anyone knows how to help me?

Comment: The input you show us is not a well-formed XML document and cannot be processed by XSLT. I am guessing that's just a typo and that your real problem is the one explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762628/3016153

Comment: Thank you, @michael.hor257k but I didn't get how to use it in my code, can you give me just one example? thanks in advance

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: The only differences between the input and the output is the output removed the namespaces.  Why do you want to remove important info that can be used to check the xml is valid?

Comment: my output is receiving empty, just "<Records />" Idk why stackoverflow erased it

Comment: StackOverflow did not "erase it". You did not format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

It does two things:

1. Removes namespaces.
2. Adds missing `<cwe_description/>` element.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Records xmlns="http://www.archer-tech.com/"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/schema/2.0/archerapi https://analysiscenter.veracode.com/resource/2.0/archerreport.xsd">
    <Record>
        <app_name>C3L-SCHEDULER</app_name>
        <app_id>1484475</app_id>
        <cwe_description>testsdsasadas</cwe_description>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <app_name>C3L-SCHEDULER</app_name>
        <app_id>1484475</app_id>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <app_name>C3L-SCHEDULER</app_name>
        <app_id>1484475</app_id>
        <cwe_description>testsdsasadsadasdsadaas</cwe_description>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns1="http://www.archer-tech.com/"
                exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- remove all namespaces -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:Record[not(ns1:cwe_description)]">
        <Record>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <cwe_description/>
        </Record>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 1.0 #2**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns1="http://www.archer-tech.com/"
                exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- remove all namespaces -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:Record[not(ns1:cwe_description)]">
        <Record>
            <app_name><xsl:value-of select="ns1:app_name"/></app_name>
            <app_id><xsl:value-of select="ns1:app_id"/></app_id>
            <cwe_description/>
            ...
        </Record>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Records>
    <Record>
        <app_name>C3L-SCHEDULER</app_name>
        <app_id>1484475</app_id>
        <cwe_description>testsdsasadas</cwe_description>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <app_name>C3L-SCHEDULER</app_name>
        <app_id>1484475</app_id>
        <cwe_description/>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <app_name>C3L-SCHEDULER</app_name>
        <app_id>1484475</app_id>
        <cwe_description>testsdsasadsadasdsadaas</cwe_description>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

Comment: Hello @Yitzhak Khabinsky, it works but, my problem is, I need cwe_description to be in the same position, and i have more fields than just these 3... it was just an example

Comment: I added XSLT 1.0 #2. That way you can compose `<Record>` element and its child elements explicitly.

Comment: thank you Yitzhak it helped me a lot, I'm really new to this

Comment: Good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. 
Please mark it as answered. You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). 
Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted".