XML Block insert into .xml file via xsltproc on Linux
I have this original.xml file tree:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/xmlns/">
    <element1>
        <name>Hi</name>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <name>Beer</name>
    </element2>
    <element2>
        <name>Balloon</name>
        <element2_1>
            <name>John</name>
        </element2_1>
    </element2> 
</root>

I am trying to add element2_2 under element2 parent. I have tried to make an insert (xslt stylesheet as part of a script) based on "xsl:element match" as following:
cat <<EOT > insert.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/element2[@name='Balloon']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:element name="element2_2">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">Edward</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOT

And then use the xsltproc to insert it the insert.xsl into original.xml based on a specific location(tag and element) on Linux:
xsltproc insert.xsl original.xml > ./updated.xml

Unfortunately nothing happens. The only thing I found was working was changing the match pattern to root ("/*") and redact the xsl:element to actual .xml element, which resulted in concatenating the element after root(not something useful).
Desired Output:
<root>
        <element1>
            <name>Hi</name>
        </element1>
        <element2>
            <name>Beer</name>
        </element2>
        <element2>
            <name>Balloon</name>
            <element2_1>
                <name>John</name>
            </element2_1>
            <element2_2>
                <name>Edward</name>
            </element2_2>
        </element2> 
    </root>

Suppose there are no differences between the environments.

Please add the expected result. Now it is not cleat what you mean by I am trying to add element2_2 under element2 parent.

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

You don't want your result in the same namespace?

@SiebeJongebloed yes, i need it in the same namespace.

Please do not make siginifcant changes to your question after it has been answered. For the newly added problem with the namespace see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762628/3016153.

@name selects an attribute of which there aren't any in the XML so I suspect you simply want (now after the namespace has been added to the input XML)
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/xmlns/"
xmlns:tc="http://www.tibco.com/xmlns/"
exclude-result-prefixes="tc">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tc:root/tc:element2[tc:name='Balloon']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        <element2_2>
          <name>Edward</name>
        </element2_2>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Demo with client-side JavaScript (where in Chromium based browsers libxslt is kind of the same processor as in xsltproc):


const xmlSource = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/xmlns/">
    <element1>
        <name>Hi</name>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <name>Beer</name>
    </element2>
    <element2>
        <name>Balloon</name>
        <element2_1>
            <name>John</name>
        </element2_1>
    </element2> 
</root>`;

const domParser = new DOMParser();

const xmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xmlSource, 'application/xml');

const xsltSource = `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/xmlns/"
xmlns:tc="http://www.tibco.com/xmlns/"
exclude-result-prefixes="tc">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tc:root/tc:element2[tc:name='Balloon']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        <element2_2>
          <name>Edward</name>
        </element2_2>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>`;

const xsltDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xsltSource, 'application/xml');

const xsltProc = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProc.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);

const resultDoc = xsltProc.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);

//console.log(resultDoc);

console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(resultDoc));




Hi Martin, I have tried your solution but this didnt help me. In the original .xml the "name" tag is an attribute. I have noticed the namespace differs between the insert.xml and original.xml, maybe thats the cause?

If there is an option for insert by pattern, say insert any after "element2 has name Balloon", this should help a lot.

In the XML you have shown in your question there are no attributes, the name is a child element. And you haven't shown any namespace declarations at all. We can only write code against the sample data you provide in your question, if your input is different then don't complain that the answer didn't help, don't waste our time by not providing the real input (minimized to show the structure, but certainly with any namespaces present).

Thank you for your time. I have updated my question accordingly. Your answer looks correct, but I cant figure out why on my env it fails. As I mentioned previously, if I change the match pattern to "/*" then the transformation works but only applied to the end of the .xml provided which is also correct but is not what I am Looking for.

@Mabadai, see the edit, the namespace needs to be taken into account.

Hi Martin, Im sorry for the mess. Should had to put more effort at the beginning and not neglect the namespace parameter in the issue. Thank you for your answer, this helped in solving my issue.
