XML transformation - duplicate node and concat string to existing tag values
Im new to xsltproc and want to transform this XML:
<services>
    <event name="Something.zip">
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <bindings>
            <binding name="Example">
                <machine>example-name</machine>
                <product>
                    <type>Shared</type>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <location>/path/to/something</location>
                </product>
            </binding>
        </bindings>
    </event>
</services>

To this one:
<services>
    <event name="Something.zip">
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <bindings>
            <binding name="Example">
                <machine>example-name</machine>
                <product>
                    <type>Shared</type>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <location>/path/to/something</location>
                </product>
            </binding>
            <binding name="Example-1">
                <machine>example-name-test</machine>
                <product>
                    <type>Shared</type>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <location>/path/to/something</location>
                </product>
            </binding>
        </bindings>
    </event>
</services>

Those are the points that I should follow:

All the original .xml file content should be preserved.
Inside bindings, I need to duplicate the current binding and take its name and add "-1" to it. Also, I need to add "-test" to the value inside the "machine" tag.
The name of each binding can vary, thus, I cannot rely on the string "Example" as constant input. Same is true for the value inside "machine" tag.
Suppose there is only one  tag in each .xml file, and there will always be 1 binding inside it.

The insert.xsl that I wrote:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://some/xml/namespace" xmlns:tc="http://some/xml/namespace" exclude-result-prefixes="tc">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tc:binding">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <binding name="{@name}-1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </binding>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

With help from y.arazim I have duplicated the binding inside the bindings and change the name attribute as suggested. Yet, cant solve how to change the  in the new Example-1 binding block.
P.S, if I have tag value with blank spaces, will the xsltproc remove those whitespaces and leave a closed tag instead? If yes, is there an option to avoid this behavior?
Working Stylesheet:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://some/xml/namespace" xmlns:tc="http://some/xml/namespace" exclude-result-prefixes="tc">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tc:binding">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <binding name="{@name}-1">
            <machine>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(tc:machine, '-test')"/>
            </machine>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::tc:machine)]"/>
        </binding>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

After long hauling, the final solution(based on y.arazim answer) was to retrieve the xml elements from the referred namespace by adding the prefix before the element.


For some reason it does nothing.

That's not true. It does something: it throws an error:
Cannot add attributes to an element if children have been already added to the element.

To get the result you show, try something like:
<xsl:template match="binding">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <binding name="{@name}-1">
        <machine>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(machine, '-test')"/>
        </machine>
        <xsl:copy-of select="product"/>
    </binding>
</xsl:template>

Do note that your stylesheet declares a default namespace xmlns="http://some/xml/namespace". I don't know whether you really want this or if that's just an attempt at "voodoo programming", but it will change the result significantly.

Re your question about spaces, see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#strip

Added: you can see it working here.

I really want this, but I mask it for security purposes. What if the binding block contents can change? Is there any alternative to the line <xsl:copy-of select="product"/> so that it will copy all the binding block content no matter what tag is inside it?

Just change <xsl:copy-of select="product"/> to <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>

Actually, it needs to be <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::machine)]"/>. Otherwise you will get another occurrence of the machine element.

I have tried your solution and makes a copy of the currently existing binding block named Example-1(which is good), then inserts another -test into it(which is not good) and finally inserts this "binding" into curently existing binding "block" and not into the parent. I have updated the template.

That is not the result I am getting with the input you have provided (see the link in my answer). Perhaps the difference is caused by your input being in a namespace and your failing to properly adjust for that.

Actually, looking at your edited code, that's not at all what I suggested.

You right. I have checked again and it works, but, I get two tags named "machine": -test and example-name

Again, I don't see that in the output I am getting with the input you have provided. Have you looked at the demo I have provided in the link?

Yes, i saw the fiddle. For some reason the fiddle runs great, but on my OS it add another tag -test. It means that the concat works on empty tag value and the copy uses no filter at all (although its written otherwise).

No, it means that either your input or your XSLT (or both) are different. IMHO you made a grave mistake by hiding the fact that your input XML is in a namespace (for "security purposes" you could have simply changed the namespace URI, as you have done with the XSLT) and now you are dealing with the consequences. Unfortunately, I don't know how to help you with input I don't see. And frankly, I have already spent much more time on this than I planned.

@Blurred_Vision The most likely reason you are getting a value of -test is that you are calling for concat(machine, '-test') but since  machine is in a namespace, no value is returned from the XML. See here how to properly handle namespaces in the input XML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762628/3016153.

@michael.hor257k Brilliant. Thank you very much Michael, the link you mentioned was very useful and clear to me.

@y.arazim Thank you for your contribution and time dedicated to the issue. I will mark your answer as solution, because it was the closest and contributed the most.

I would be inclined to tackle this using modes:
<xsl:template match="binding">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="dup"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="binding/@name" mode="dup">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '-1')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="binding/machine" mode="dup">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '-test')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

and make sure that the identity template also applies to mode dup.

How do you "make sure that the identity template also applies to mode dup" in XSLT 1.0?

I didn't spell it out because I haven't used XSLT 1.0 for over 20 years, so I have to look it up. Which you could do just as well yourself. Looks like you need to add another copy of the identity template rule that specifies mode="dup".

I did look it up. So: 4 templates instead of one? For what?

For separation of concerns, modularity, and reusability.

Those are noble principles. But when you insist on implementing them regardless of any other consideration, there is an ugly word for that.

Well, it's a value judgement. Without knowing the background to the project, and its likely future directions, it's impossible to know how much effort to put into writing code that will stand the test of time.
